# Throw an error when the error comes in the payload of a 200 status code

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have one API that returns errors in several ways (I know it's not very good idea but it's a legacy API). I have to concatenate three API calls only if the previous call is successful, I have working this approach except for some cases that returns errors in payload (With a 200 status). For do this I want to use Spring Web Client and I do the following:

```
Mono
        .when(placeOrderCall)
        .doOnSuccess(response -> {
          if (!isSuccesful(response)) {
              throw new Exception("");
          }
        })
        .then(changeSubscription)
        .doOnSuccess(response -> {
          if (!isSuccesful(response)) {
            throw new Exception("");
          }
        })
        .then(httpCall)
        .doOnSuccess(response -> {
          if (!isSuccesful(response)) {
            throw new Exception("");
          }
        })
        .doOnError(error -> System.out.println("Error"))
        .block();
```

But I can't throw an exception in `doOnSuccess`...I want to break the flow and send it to `doOnError`. Is this posible?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since, you haven't mentioned why you are not able to throw exception in `doOnSuccess` so I am guessing that it is because of `checked Exception`. So, for this, simple solution is to throw `RuntimeException` like below -

`throw new RuntimeException("");`

Answer (score 0):

Please, read reactor documentation part about [handle()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_handle) method.

Your code can be rewritten as following then:

```
   Mono
    .when(placeOrderCall)
    .handle((res, sink) -> {
      if (!isSuccesful(response)) {
        sink.error(new Exception(""));
      } else {
        sink.next(res);
      }
    })
    .then(changeSubscription)
    .handle((res, sink) -> {
      if (!isSuccesful(response)) {
        sink.error(new Exception(""));
      } else {
        sink.next(res);
      }
    })
    .then(httpCall)
    .handle((res, sink) -> {
      if (!isSuccesful(response)) {
        sink.error(new Exception(""));
      } else {
        sink.next(res);
      }
    })
    .doOnError(error -> System.out.println("Error"))
    .block();
```

In case any handle method executes `sink.error()` the subsequent `then()` functions won't be called and only the last `.doOnError()` will be invoked.